# Creating a lookup table in CHISEL

Tags: scala, hdl, lookup-tables, file-read, chisel

I am trying to create a lookup table in Chisel of width 72 bits and 1024 entries. These 1024 entries are stored separately in a file, which I read into my code. The code I have written so far is:

```
import Chisel._
import scala.io.Source._

module mdlNm {  
    // function to read entries from file 'omega_i.dat'      
    def fileRead() = { 
        val fileIn = fromFile("omega_i.dat").getLines.toList
        val num    = fileIn.map(i => BigInt(i, 16)) // converting the hexadecimal entries from string to BigInt
        val uInt   = num.map(i => UInt(i, width = 72)) // converting BigInt entries to UInt of width 72
        ROM (uInt) // Chisel construct for creating an LUT for fixed entries
    }

    // The above LUT is later read as follows:
    val in = Bits("h123") // Any 10-bit input to the LUT
    val lutOut = fileRead().read(in) // Value read from the LUT
}
```

The above code throws up many errors of the form:

```
cppBackend//sinCos.cpp:2407:23: error: ‘T1785’ was not declared in this scope
{ T425.put(1018, 0, T1785[0]); T425.put(1018, 1, T1785[1]);}
                   ^
cppBackend//sinCos.cpp:2408:23: error: ‘T1786’ was not declared in this scope
{ T425.put(1019, 0, T1786[0]); T425.put(1019, 1, T1786[1]);}
                   ^
cppBackend//sinCos.cpp:2409:23: error: ‘T1787’ was not declared in this scope
{ T425.put(1020, 0, T1787[0]); T425.put(1020, 1, T1787[1]);}
                   ^
cppBackend//sinCos.cpp:2410:23: error: ‘T1788’ was not declared in this scope
{ T425.put(1021, 0, T1788[0]); T425.put(1021, 1, T1788[1]);}
                   ^
cppBackend//sinCos.cpp:2411:23: error: ‘T1789’ was not declared in this scope
{ T425.put(1022, 0, T1789[0]); T425.put(1022, 1, T1789[1]);}
                   ^
cppBackend//sinCos.cpp:2412:23: error: ‘T1790’ was not declared in this scope
{ T425.put(1023, 0, T1790[0]); T425.put(1023, 1, T1790[1]);}
```

However, when I change the `width` of `uInt` to any number `<= 64`, no such issues arise and the code works properly.
Is there an alternative way to create an LUT of the size I specified above, in Chisel? Or am I doing something wrong in the above code?
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In chisel3,, the current version, this would be constructed a little bit differently. `VecInit` is used instead of ROM
I would recommend the creation of an intermediate value lut to hold the rom created by `buildLookupTable`
because each call to `buildLookupTable` would read the file again and create another rom.

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import firrtl.FileUtils

class SomeModule extends MultiIOModule {
  def buildLookupTable(): Vec[UInt] = {
    VecInit(FileUtils.getLines("file1.dat").map { s => BigInt(s, 16).U })
  }

  val lut = buildLookupTable()

  // The above LUT is later read as follows:
  val in = 0x123.U       // Any 10-bit input to the LUT
  val lutOut = lut(in)   // Value read from the LUT

  // rest of module
  ...
}
```

I don't know what the problem with lengths you had but I have tested the above with `UInt`s with widths of 500 and it works fine.